# How to include C library in Android without SWIG

Tags: android, c, cmake, swig, circleci

I need to include a C library (source files) into an Android project. The sample app I was given uses Cmake and SWIG to create the library and to link it...and I've gotten it to work in my own app.

However, I'm running into issues getting SWIG on our CI server (circle CI).

What other ways are there to include C libraries in Android (and eventually iOS) projects?

Can I include just the .so file? (I believe the output of Cmake is a .so file.)
Is there an alternative to SWIG for bridging between Java code and the C code?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can do this using JNI, if you don't want to use C++ just wrap your exported function declarations in extern "C" {} -- if it's a third party library you can make an extern "C" wrapper intermediate library

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDignan, turns out I had to replace some `swig_` function calls in CMakeLists with their non-swig counterparts.

Comment: much better to use swig if you can